# make 'spree install' to add http link in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

When i do:

```
spree install
```

It adds these 2 lines in my Gemfile.

```
gem 'spree_gateway', :github => 'spree/spree_gateway'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => 'edge'
```

Later it tries to do **bundle install**, i get this error

```
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git (at master)
```

This is because my network proxy does not allow me to do connect with **git://** but it can connect with **http://**

How to change the code added by spree to make it connect with **http** or how to make rails to connect **:github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise'** with **http**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using rvm, your gems will be installed under your home directory's `.rvm` folder.  If you're using a system ruby instead, they will be under the system ruby's location, probably `/usr/local/bin`.  In either case, find the spree gem folder by looking under the appropriate location with the subfolder `lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems` and looking for spree.

Once you've found it, find the file `cmd/lib/spree_cmd/installer.rb`.  Edit: Seems you found yours here: `/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/spree_cmd-1.3.0/lib/spree_cmd`. You'll have to experiment here, because I don't know exactly how it works, but I would work with the lines in the `add_gem` function.  Try changing

```
gem :spree, @spree_gem_options
```

to

```
gem :spree, :git => 'http://github.com/spree/spree.git'
```

Comment: Works like a charm! thanks! spree_cmd is a gem & I have found the installer.rb file in this path in my system. /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/spree_cmd-1.3.0/lib/spree_cmd

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you might need to change the syntax a little bit if your behind proxy..

`gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'http://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git'` .

Please check if this works.

Comment: No. **Spree install** automatically adds the lines to Gemfile and runs bundle install, Later it has many things to do like running migrations. So manually editing Gemfile doesnt work